# Как определить тип данных в Си

Tags: c

Из файла нужно считать первые 2 символа(с учетом того, что в файли 2 и более символов) и нужно определить, образуют ли они число или нет, если да, то четное или нет. Как определить цифры это или нет и как сделать из них число?

Comment: Ну, например, цифры ли это :)

Comment: @Harry Пардон :)

Comment: Считать символ и посмотреть, попадает ли он в диапазон от `'0'` до `'9'` или нет. Или использовать `isdigit()`. А как сделать из цифр 7 и 8 число 78 - ну уж догадайтесь сами :)

Comment: @Harry Спасибо большое!!! Очень помог)))